Lizmap User and Date are not being stored
I have a table in my WebGIS where users can add elements. There are two fields with automatic calculation:

Lizmap user
Date at the time of creation

The problem is that sometimes this information gets saved, but other times it doesn't.
Could this be related to the server access speed?

"WebSIG" or "WebGIS"?

Ups, WebSIG is in my native language.
